# Send serial data to Lightblue Bean(a BLE arduino)

Tags: unity-game-engine, arduino, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm working on a Unity project. In my project, I just want to send color information to Lightblue Bean (a low energy Bluetooth Arduino) to control the light color.

I'm trying to send serial data from Unity to Bean BY `SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.LightBlue-Bean)`; But it gives me this error:

```
IOException: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I was thinking about using the `/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port`, but I couldn't enable the Use for Virtual Serial (/dev/cu.LightBlue-Bean) function then.

Then I tried to read all the serial port name from Unity. But the `ports.Length` is always ZERO. (code is listed following):

```cpp
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
Debug.Log (ports.Length);
for(int i=0; i<ports.Length; i++)
    Debug.Log (ports[i]);
```

Can you give me some advice?

And if I succeed in doing this, will it work immediately for an Android phone if I build an APK file?